# Is it normal to have such NSMutableArray structure

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I'm having a problem when setting `UITableViewCell` with an NSMutableArray.

```
-[__NSCFArray isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

and in that line:

```
cellDetailed.favouriteLabel.text=[arrayofFavouriteNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

When NSLogging the NSMutableArray, I have this:

```
favourites: (
        (
        "User1"
    ),
        (
        User2
    )
)
```

Is it the structure of an NSMutableArray is like:

```
favourites: (
"a",
"b",
"c"
)
```

When adding a value as favourites, I'm firstly having the old favourites:

```
arrayofFavouritesNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"favourites_names"]];
```

then, adding the new value to the NSMutableArray:

```
[arrayofFavouritesNames addObject:name];
```

Then setting the updated NSMutableArray:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:arrayofFavouritesTeamsNames forKey:@"favourites_names"];
```

I really don't know why I'm having that error in `UITableViewCell`, but I guess that it's related to the structure of the NSMutableArray.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: You have an array of array of strings, not simply an array of strings.

Comment: @H2CO3: This is what I noticed, don't know from where it's coming :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your debug output shows an array of arrays of strings.  That is to say:

- Your top level object (`arrayofFavouritesNames`) is an array.
- Each element of the top-level array is an array.
- Each element of each second-level array is a string.

So you are setting `name` to an array, not a string.  Set it to a string before you add it to `arrayofFavouritesNames`.

If you need more help, edit your question to show us how you set `name`.

Comment: Yes yes yes, name is an array ! How I did not notice that ?! Thank you very much .

Answer (score 2):

For get value you need to write

```
NSLog (@"%@", [[arrayofFavouritesNames objectAtIndexPath:0] objectAtIndexPath:0]);
```

If you get all value from array then use `for loop`
Such like,

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < arrayofFavouritesNames.count ; i++)
{
  NSLog (@"%@", [[arrayofFavouritesNames objectAtIndexPath:i] objectAtIndexPath:i]);
}
```